# Texts going to email

Tags: contacts, sync

I have a news Samsung S6, and when someone who is in my contact list texts me, it not only comes to my phone but goes to my email inbox. How can I stop this?

Comment: What email app are you using?

Comment: Just the app that came on the phone. Even when someone phones me, there number also appears on my email.